# Big Differences Between Linux System Calls and INT 80 Software Interrupts

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

From a not so far removed picture of what is going on, could someone expound more on what is the difference between Linux's system calls like read() and write() etc. and writing them in assembly using the x86 INT opcode along with setting up the specified registers?

Comment: Asking difference between "syscall" and "writing syscall in assembly" is like asking difference between "book" and "writing book". One is the entity, other is the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual function `read()` is a C library wrapper over what is called the 'system call gate' . The C library wrapper is primarily responsible for things like setting `errno` on failure, as well as mapping between structures used in userspace and those used by the low-level syscall.

The system call gate, in turn, is what actually switches from usermode to kernel mode. This depends on the CPU architecture - on x86, you have two options - one is to use `INT 080h` after setting up registers with the syscall number and arguments; another is to call into a symbol provided by a library mapped into every executable's address space, with the same register setup. This library then picks between several potential options for user->kernel transitions, including `SYSENTER`, `SYSCALL`, or a fallback to `INT 080h`. Other architectures use yet different methods. In any case, the CPU shifts into kernelspace, where the syscall number is used to lookup the appropriate handler in a big table.

Answer (score 0):

interrupt is not the only way to invoke system call, you use special instructs like sysenter, syscall or simple jump to specific address in protected mode.